# how to get process id from a container?

Tags: node.js, docker

How do I get the process IDs of programs (nodejs in this example) running in a container?
When I use `docker top test1` (test1 is the container's name)
I get

```
UID                 PID                 PPID                C                   STIME               TTY                 TIME                CMD
root                54682               54654               0                   12:38               ?                   00:00:00            /sbin/docker-init -- docker-entrypoint.sh node src/server.js
root                54728               54682               0                   12:38               ?                   00:00:00            node src/server.js
```

Note the PIDS are `54682` and `54728` but when I run top from inside the container after running `docker container exec -it test1 sh`, I get different PIDs (`7`and `1`)

```
  PID  PPID USER     STAT   VSZ %VSZ CPU %CPU COMMAND
    7     1 root     S     248m   6%   1   0% node src/server.js
   15     0 root     S     1664   0%   0   0% sh
   22    15 root     R     1596   0%   0   0% top
    1     0 root     S     1084   0%   0   0% /sbin/docker-init -- docker-entrypoint.sh node src/server.js
```

The use case for my requirement is that our application uses node's process.pid to write unique log file names per service.
our log files are named using a format like service.process.pid.log (healthcheck.400.log).

Comment: The main process in the container will always be pid 1 in the process namespace, with the rights and responsibilities that entails.  Do you have any particular application code that depends on knowing the pids, either in container or host context?  Usually you can use `docker` commands to manipulate the single container process and don't explicitly need to know its pid.

Comment: I understand that pid 1 will always be id of the main process. What I am trying to find out is to how to find out the process ids of the programs running inside a container.  I added clarification to the question as to why I am trying to find out process Id without having to exec inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

The PIDs are relative to the environment you ran top in. On your host machine the container process's PIDs are `54682` and `54728` and in the container the PIDs are `7` and `1`.

Comment: Do you mean that I have no way of finding out the actual PIDs of processes inside the container from the host? if that's the case, what is the point of having docker top ?

Comment: Using `docker container exec` you can. I presume `docker top` is to save you the hassle of filtering your top output.